# Elementary OS Loki hangs during shutdown

Tags: release-loki, shutdown

After 2 years without an issue, since 2 days ago my Loki has started freezing during the shutdown (as well as rebooting) process.
I have tried the most common solutions found on the internet (working on GRUB, booting into an earlier Kernel), but to no avail.
When I shut down, it freezes on the shutdown image (elementary OS logo, at this point not "pulsating" any longer, just stuck, and the screeen won't turn off). Pressing ESC reveal what you can see in the picture below, fixed and unchanged.
I will be very grateful to anyone trying to help with this!

[image]

ADDENDUM:
Running   `apt policy systemd`
Gives me

```
systemd:
  Installed: 229-4ubuntu21.10
  Candidate: 229-4ubuntu21.10
  Version table:
 *** 229-4ubuntu21.10 500
        500 http://it.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     229-4ubuntu4 500
        500 http://it.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
```

Comment: Did you updated systemd recently? | Could you run the command `apt policy systemd`?

Comment: That's very likely. Added the output in the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bug was resolved with the latest kernel update, version 4.15.0-42-generic.
No further action was required

Answer (score 1):

I could tell you to downgrade `systemd` right away, but you will be able to do it only to the first release not the last update. You'll miss a lot of fixes with it, check the changelog below for more details.

http://changelogs.ubuntu.com/changelogs/pool/main/s/systemd/systemd_229-4ubuntu21.10/changelog

I recommend you to report this to:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/systemd

, and then decide what to do.

---

Now If you want to test to downgrade `systemd` anyway...

Run:

```
sudo apt install systemd=229-4ubuntu4
```

Hold that version:

```
sudo apt-mark hold systemd
```

---

You'll probably have some unmet dependencies like `libsystemd0`

Just add that dependency to the line

```
sudo apt install systemd=229-4ubuntu4 libsystemd0=<version_needed>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your advice. As you foresaw, I need to add that line for adjusting the dependancies. However, installing those dependancies will prompt the removal of great part of my DE (appcenter, pantheon-files pantheon-shell pantheon-xsession-settings, gnome-settings-daemon etc.)

Comment: https://pastebin.com/zGeiFvrE (check the lower portion for the exact output of the command)

Comment: then you can't downgrade... maybe the base version of `xenial` differs from the base of `loki`

Comment: It shouldn't be any different, as far as I know. Is there a way to retain those packages, or would cause great trouble (e.g. really break my system)?

Comment: Could really break the system

Comment: A new Kernel upgrade has fixed the bug for good. Thank you very much for your help, Sebastian