# Taking time on Shutdown and when boot after that then the just logo flashes

Tags: release-juno, boot, shutdown

Sometimes when i shut Down then the shutdowns takes time and when I open the Os next time it does not o[pen it shows the elementary OS logo and the logo flickers or the some random stuffs which have in brackets OK like this

```
[OK] some words
```

then I shutdown by holding power button and then open again .The system boots after some attempts .

Last time when I shutdown I had one node process running and i Just clicked on shutdown icon and then shutdown . But this may not be the case all time .
I had found one answer but it says that the problem is solved in kernel   version 4.15.0-42-generic but i am running Linux 4.15.0-47-generic 
 [here is the answer](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/a/17607/17742)
[image: here the error]

[image: it just repeating]

Comment: solved here https://askubuntu.com/questions/1134720/problem-on-booting-of-linux

Comment: it does not solve mine

Answer (score 1):

> According to [Dewa Sembiring on askubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/a/1134731/907048),
>
> > Go to tty
> >     mode using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>, if you can't,
> >     insert a live cd then get into `chroot`, try to reinstall your
> >     `plymouth` but before reinstalling the `plymouth`, try to reconfigure
> >     the `plymouth` first,
> >
> > ```
> > sudo dpkg-reconfigure plymouth && sudo update-initramfs -u
> > ```
> >
> > if it doesn't work. then reinstall it,
> >
> > ```
> > sudo apt-get install --reinstall plymouth
> > ```

Answer (score 1):

What helps to me in a similar situation was to reinstall plymouth. I recommend doing it on recovery mode - on the grub bootloader screen select **advanced options for elementary os** and on the next screen choose the **[recovery mode]** option. Once there first select '**Configure network**' in order to have a network connection and after this choose **Root**.

Once there type in the console

```
apt install --reinstall plymouth*
```

The * is necessary because you need to reinstall the plymouth-themes and other packages in order to fix the problem. Only plymouth doesn't worked for me.

Good luck

[source](https://elementaryforums.com/index.php?threads/solved-plymouth-bootsplash-problems.2434/)

Comment: i will try it ...